# bootstrap check-all column is this even a feature?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a check-all feature to a table, but cannot seem to find how to do this in any bootstrap documentation. Is this even a bootstrap feature?

Here is what my table looks like.... I could add in what I have tried for the check column, but nothing has worked, so I mite as well start with a clean slate.

```
<table id="datatable-basic-markerpage" class="table table-sorting table-striped table-hover datatable">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="20%">Username</th>
                <th width="20%">gender</th>
                <th width="20%">Visits</th>
                <th width="20%">New Visits</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
               <tbody>
                <?php
                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $url = "profilepage.php?username=" . $row['username'];
                         $lat2 = $row['usrhomelat'];
                         $lon2 = $row['usrhomelng'];
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . "<a href='" . $url . "'> " . $row['username'] . " </a>" . "</td>";
                                echo "<td >" . $gender . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                                                }
                 ?>
               </tbody>
    </table>
```

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appriciated

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle ? didnt get what output you required ?

Comment: Since bootstrap and jQuery work on pure html, it easier to diagnose the issue if you provide the actual html created instead of the *server side code*.

Answer (score 0):

In you code you dont have checkboxes?

Because you didnt make a working fiddle, and no checkboxes,  i wrtited you some common solution

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr("checked")){
    $('#checkboxes').find('span').addClass('checked');        
  }else{
    $('#checkboxes').find('span').removeClass('checked');
  }    
});
```